# Need correct syntax of callback/change to redirect users to respective urls

Tags: javascript, callback

My first post so please take it easy on me ;)...

The following code is a menu that allows me to click on a menu item and be redirected to a specific URL.  Using the code below however, I receive an error that says:

unexpected token ":"<--referring to the line beginning with ret === 0 ?"

If I remove the last two window.location.assign commands it will work for the first two items in the menu.  I'm assuming it's my syntax, what in the heck am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

### Elias

4 item MENU

```
    </div>

    <script src="plugin/react-with-addons.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="plugin/react-dom.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script src="plugin/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    new CA_select({
        selector: document.getElementById('fs_3'),
        iconColor: '#fff',
        bgColor: '#00BCD4',
        items: [
            {class: "fa-thumbs-up"},
            {class: "fa-thumbs-down"},
            {class: "fa-arrow-right"},
            {class: "fa-arrow-left"}
        ],
        callback: true,
        change: (ret) => {
            ret === 0 ? window.location.assign("https://www.url1.com") : window.location.assign("https://www.url2.com") : window.location.assign("https://www.url3.com") : window.location.assign("https://www.url4.com") : 
        },

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Elias, you use a ternary operator but the syntax is as follows: condition ? trueCase : falseCase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a syntax error.

This is wrong

ret === 0 ? window.location.assign("https://www.url1.com") : window.location.assign("https://www.url2.com") : window.location.assign("https://www.url3.com") : window.location.assign("https://www.url4.com") :

Ternary operator can only take 2 expressions. one when TRUE and one when FALSE.

This is how it is supposed to be

condition ? expr1 : expr2

For more you can check

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

In your case you can use switch case inside change function

```
change: (ret) => {
   switch(ret) {
      case "0":
         // window.location.assign("https://www.url2.com");
         break;
      case "1":
         // window.location.assign("https://www.url3.com");
         break;

   }
},
```

Comment: Understood.  I see that now Thank You!  What should I use to achieve my desired result?  I want to redirect the user to URL1 2..3..4... based on which item they choose.!

Comment: I tried it and thought it was working but it's now saying "Unexpected keyword 'case'. Expected a closing '}' after a method body.                      Here is the code:

Comment: new CA_select({
   selector: document.getElementById('fs_3'),
   iconColor: '#fff',
   bgColor: '#00BCD4',
   items: [
    {class: "fa-thumbs-up"},
    {class: "fa-thumbs-down"},
    {class: "fa-arrow-right"},
    {class: "fa-arrow-left"},
   ],
   callback: true,
   switch(ret) {
      case "0":
         // window.location.assign("https://www.url2.com");
         break;
      case "1":
         // window.location.assign("https://www.url3.com");
         break;

   },
  });
  
  </script>

Comment: Can you see my answer. I specified you should put switch case inside change function. But you removed change function.

Comment: Here is what I did: callback: true,
   change: (ret) => {
     switch(ret) {
       case "0":
         window.location.assign("https://www.url1.com");
         break;
  case "1":
         window.location.assign("https://www.url2.com");
         break;
  case "2":
         window.location.assign("https://www.url3.com");
         break;
  case "3":
         window.location.assign("https://www.url4.com");
         break;     
   }    
  }
  
  </script